# read file from Azure Blob Storage into Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I have already tested this design using a local SQL Server Express set-up.

I uploaded several .json files to Azure Storage
In SQL Database, I created an External Data source:

`CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureStorage
  WITH 
   (TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION = 'https://mydatafilestest.blob.core.windows.net/my_dir
    );`

Then I tried to query the file using my External Data Source:

```
select *
from OPENROWSET
 (BULK 'my_test_doc.json', DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureStorage', SINGLE_CLOB) as data
```

However, this failed with the error message "Cannot bulk load. The file "prod_EnvBlow.json" does not exist or you don't have file access rights."

Do I need to configure a DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL to access the file storage, as described here?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-scoped-credential-transact-sql

What else can anyone see that has gone wrong and I need to correct?

Comment: did you find a way to do this in the end? (i.e. not using `OPENROWSET`)

Comment: @joshi123 - I have not be able to re-visit this for quite a while so have no update.

Comment: I found a solution, see answer below!

Answer (score 2):

`OPENROWSET` is currently not supported on Azure SQL Database as explained in this [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql). You may use `BULK INSERT` to insert data into a temporary table and then query this table. See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) for documentation on `BULK INSERT`.

Comment: although this documentation, published a week after the `OPENROWSET` docs, seems to state that `OPENROWSET` is supported in SQL Azure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/import-json-documents-into-sql-server - looks like this feature is now in public preview, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/roadmap/files-from-azure-blob-storage-to-sql-database/

Answer (score 2):

Now that `OPENROWSET` is in public preview, the following works. Nb the key option is in case your blob is not public. I tried it on a private blob with the scoped credential option and it worked. nnb if you are using a SAS key make sure you delete the leading `?` so the string should start with `sv` as shown below.

Make sure the `blobcontainer/my_test_doc.json` section specifies the correct path e.g. `container/file`.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyAzureBlobStorageCredential
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'sv=2017****************';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
   LOCATION = 'https://yourstorage.blob.core.windows.net',
   CREDENTIAL= MyAzureBlobStorageCredential);

DECLARE @json varchar(max)
SELECT @json = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'blobcontainer/my_test_doc.json', 
SINGLE_BLOB, DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage',
            FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage') as j;

select @json;
```

More detail provided in these [docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/preview-loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-sql-database/)